# simple question about rtabmap

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am just simple guy, I have robot and want my robot avoiding obstacles.

I dont have much furniture in my room, but certainly I want that my robot could avoid tables with thin legs.

I want to use some camera because lidar does not help in this case.

I have jetson tx2, turtlebot3 waffle, lidar, and d435 camera.

I am trying to use rtabmap to project such tables on 2d occupancy grid.

And rtabmap does not project obstacles at all. There is nothing from camera on 2d occupancy grid.

[image: image description]

As I understand rtabmap should project obstacles onto 2d map, right? Maybe, I dont understand something about using rtabmap.

**MaxObstacleHeight** is set to **1.7** meters. I tried to set **Grid/MapFrameProjection** to **true**, still does not help.

```
<param name="RGBD/NeighborLinkRefining" type="string" value="true"/>
<param name="RGBD/ProximityBySpace" type="string" value="true"/>
<param name="RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd" type="string" value="false"/>
<param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate" type="string" value="0.05"/>
<param name="RGBD/LinearUpdate" type="string" value="0.05"/>
<param name="Optimizer/Slam2D" type="string" value="true"/>
<param name="Reg/Force3DoF" type="string" value="true"/>
<param name="Reg/Strategy" type="string" value="1"/> <!— 1=ICP —>
<param name="Vis/MinInliers" type="string" value="5"/>
<param name="Vis/InlierDistance" type="string" value="0.1"/>
<param name="Kp/MaxDepth" type="string" value="1.75"/>
<param name="Vis/MaxDepth" type="string" value="1.75"/>
<param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr" type="string" value="700"/>
<param name="Rtabmap/DetectionRate" type="string" value="$(arg rate)" />
<param name="Mem/RehearsalSimilarity" type="string" value="0.45"/>
<param name="Grid/MaxObstacleHeight" type="string" value="1.7" />
<param name="Grid/NoiseFilteringRadius" type="string" value="0.05"/>
<param name="Grid/NoiseFilteringMinNeighbors" type="string" value="5"/>
```

what can I do to make my robot avoiding obstacles? why there is no obstacles on 2d map? Are they supposed to be projected?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336622/simple-question-about-rtabmap/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-11-03**:
If the turtlebot has a lidar, the map may be created from laser scans. In your case, you want the map to be created from the camera. Set explictiy `Grid/FromDepth` to true. See @FailFTW answer for more info and optimized segmentation approach if we are moving in 2D.

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-04**:
Thanks for your support!

I left comment down to @FailFTW answer.

Grid/FromDepth parameter has really changed my 2d map as I want, but 2d map is very teared into pieces.

https://yadi.sk/i/dnuxOQ6GRENmLA

which parameters can I change to make 2d map more continuous?

You can answer down to @FailFTW answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

setting  `Grid/NoiseFilteringRadius = 0` helped

---

Originally posted by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) with karma: 83 on 2019-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found this thread: http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Proj-map-min-obstacles-height-td2866.html

Try these settings I tested them in my sim. RTABMap should be publishing to "/rtabmap/proj_map":

```
<param name="Grid/FromDepth"             type="bool" value="true"/>
<param name="Grid/MaxGroundHeight"       type="string" value="0.2"/>
<param name="Grid/MaxObstacleHeight"     type="string" value="2"/>
<param name="Grid/NormalsSegmentation"   type="string" value="false"/>
```

Here's a the relevant part of my launch file for reference:

```
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find frc_robot)/config/slam.yaml"/>

<group ns="rtabmap">
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="rgbd_sync" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/rgbd_sync" output="screen">
  <remap from="rgb/image"       to="/$(arg camera_frame)/rgb/image_raw"/>
  <remap from="depth/image"     to="/$(arg camera_frame)/depth/image_raw"/>
  <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/$(arg camera_frame)/rgb/camera_info"/>
  <remap from="rgbd_image"      to="rgbd_image"/> <!-- Output -->
</node>

<!-- SLAM -->
<node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
  <remap from="scan" to="/scan"/>

Ignore these params below. I'm using Hector_Slam for localization.
  <param name="odom_frame_id"            type="string" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_tf_linear_variance"  type="double" value="0.0005"/>
  <param name="odom_tf_angular_variance"    type="double" value="0.0005"/>

</node>
</group>
```

And my YAML file:

```
rtabmap:
  rtabmap:
    frame_id: base_link
    map_frame_id: map
    odom_frame_id: odom
  
    subscribe_depth: false
    subscribe_rgb: false
    subscribe_rgbd: true
    subscribe_scan: true
  
    publish_tf: false
  
    Reg/Strategy: 2
    Reg/Force3DoF: true
    RGBD/ProximityBySpace: false
  
    RGBD/ProximityPathMaxNeighbors: 10
    Grid/Scan2dUnknownSpaceFilled: true
  
    Grid/FromDepth: true
    Grid/MaxGroundHeight: 0.2
    Grid/MaxObstacleHeight: 2.0
    Grid/NormalsSegmentation: false
```

---

Originally posted by [FailFTW](https://answers.ros.org/users/40686/failftw/) with karma: 21 on 2019-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-04**:
Thanks for your reply! I really appreciate your help!

I set Grid/FromDepth parameter to true and it fully changed 2d map.

table become projected onto the floor but 2d map is very teared into pieces.

here is screenshot:

https://yadi.sk/i/dnuxOQ6GRENmLA

so, I suppose path planning is impossible with this map.

which parameters can I change to make 2d map more continuous?

And also, what is the difference between subscribe_depth and subscribe_rgbd? What does rgbd_sync exactly do? I have d435, should I use rgbd_sync?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-11-04**:
You can combine `Grid/FromDepth=true`, `Grid/3D=false`, `Grid/RayTracing=true` to fill empty space. `subscribe_depth` is the legacy approach kept for backward compatibility, as `subscribe_rgbd` is now the new recommended approach with `rgbd_sync` when we subscribe to a lidar at the same time. So if you are subscribing only the camera, `subscribe_depth` is fine. If you input also the lidar, use `rgbd_sync`. Examples on this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot) have been all updated with `rgbd_sync`.

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-05**:
I have tried both,

1. with Grid/FromDepth=true, Grid/3D=false, Grid/RayTracing=true.
2. and also with using rgbd_sync

**in first case**, 2d map is quite smooth, but obstacles is not enough projected, chair's legs is projected, chair's seat is not projected, table is somehow projected, but not good enough.

https://yadi.sk/i/LykU1kQOPfFMWw

https://pastebin.com/x9v3Sg0E

**in second case**, nothing is projected, its like map is build only with lidar.

https://yadi.sk/i/IQm6K8EWJKQ1Bw

I tried to set subscribe_scan to false, and Grid/RayTracing to true here, and its better, but table is not good enough again.

https://yadi.sk/i/KxiZnESqxblEJQ

https://pastebin.com/fajcZNrM

**What can you recommend to project table as black rectangle on 2d map?**

What do you think about using pointcloud_to_laserscan? Will it help?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-11-05**:
Setting `Grid/3D=false` is a simple way to get ray tracing at low cost, but it may clear obstacle if the camera goes under the table for example. To keep everything while tracing empty space, set `Grid/3D=true` for higher computation cost. See Figures 14-16 and Table 10 of this [paper](https://introlab.3it.usherbrooke.ca/mediawiki-introlab/images/7/7a/Labbe18JFR_preprint.pdf) for a comparison of these parameters.

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-06**:
I have noticed that `Grid/3D=false` is better for projecting table.

I set `Grid/MaxObstacleHeight=2.0`, and why table is still not well projected?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-11-06**:
Do you have a database to share? Do you use `Grid/NormalsSegmentation=false` like in this answer?

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-06**:
I was running demo_bag.launch from [this](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-JAPAN-GIT/turtlebot3_slam_3d) package, Full version (1.2GB) bag file.

There, I was changing parameters in [rtabmap.launch](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-JAPAN-GIT/turtlebot3_slam_3d/blob/master/launch/rtabmap.launch) file.

As I remember, in previous comments I was testing with `Grid/NormalsSegmentation=false`, then I changed it to `true` and table with approximately 1 meter height was still not well projected.

here is this launch file: https://pastebin.com/FL4rbgPV

Then I applied this launch file to my **real robot** where d435 camera is located on the mast at 1 meter from the ground.

And I think I've got almost good projection. Here is some video: https://yadi.sk/i/8TIEWqrn94ghWw
and launch file: https://pastebin.com/JmHwjJYU

I dont have database of my real room yet.

I think I am gonna try placing camera upper and looking towards the floor.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-11-07**:
In the launch file, remove `Grid/NoiseFilteringRadius` parameter or set it to zero (disabled). You will get a lot more obstacles.

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-12**:
thanks! thats good to know!

I changed it and 2d map totally has changed.

do you also have something like detailed handbook with no need to ask you containing all such kind of information about these parameters?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-11-16**:
There is no handbook, the only documentation about parameters is when doing `$ rtabmap --params` or looking at the **Preferences** menu in rtabmap standalone (you can mouse over parameters to see a label telling what is the parameter name on ROS). Other documentation can be found on [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) and its [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials).